# Vista side bar world clock gadgets?

Tags: windows-vista, desktop-gadget, sidebar

I am searching for a free analog world clock gadget for Windows vista Sidebar . I found some of the [world clock](http://www.worldtimeserver.com/clocks/vista24hr.aspx) are good . But they are not simple and they are working only on on line .

Comment: joe, for the amount of rep you have, I would imagine you could take a little more time to use proper sentence structure and punctuation. Editing...

Comment: It happens, but just a friendly suggestion :)

Comment: Good thing I looked before hitting the **Save your edits** button :)

Comment: Sorry alex. this time i didn't give the chance to you . if you don't mind , can u make a try ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out these on the Microsoft site:

[Clocks](http://gallery.live.com/results.aspx?pl=1&bt=1&q=clock)